# Cassandra schema design viability

Tags: cassandra

I'm evaluating cassandra for a project of mine and I'm interested to know the viability of a basic cassandra schema design having millions of column families with millions of rows. Each row would have an upper limit of 30,000 columns. Is this a viable design for a distributed cassandra cluster (5-10 nodes), or am I missing something?

I'm also interested to know the viability of retrieving all of the columns from a single row in one transaction. The reason I want to do this is to sort them by their value before returning them to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Millions of column families is currently not viable in cassandra. The upper limit in recent versions is somewhere in the thousands. Additionally the dataset you described (millions of cfs x millions of rows) indicates a minimum of 1 trillion rows. Of course it depends on the specifics of a cluster but this number of rows/amount of data will require a much larger cluster than 5-10 nodes. Cassandra is much better off with lots of medium sized nodes opposed to very large and powerful nodes.

Regarding retrieving all the columns at once, the default maximum request size is 15mb. This can be changed but you almost certainly don't want to change it. Your queries most likely shouldn't be approaching that maximum request, as large allocations like that are hard on the JVM. Is there a reason it needs to be in a single transaction though? You can easily page through a row in a few requests in order to get all of the columns, and then sort at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since my original post I've narrowed it down to just a few column families with millions of rows with thousands of columns. The info on max query size is very useful. I wanted to get as many rows as possible at once simply to minimize the round trips to the server.